# How to check if user has publish_stream permission synchrounously?

Tags: javascript, facebook

When somebody clicks on a button I want to check if the user has the publish_stream permission, if he does have it, we continue with our function.

I currently made it in the following way:

```
function facebookLogin(callback)
{
    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('We should save the access token');
            callback();
       } else {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
         jGrowl('Without authorizing our application you will not be able to access all features.');
       }
     }, {scope: 'publish_stream,'});
}
```

Callback is the action i want to execute after user gave me the publish_stream permission. I would like to first check if the permission though before doing the facebook login function.

Why I want it synchrounously? Because i need to do it in the click even handler, else browsers start complaining that im randomly opening popups so it should be done synchrounously i think.

Thanks a lot, getting desperate with the js and facebook, after a long late day.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the greatest solution, but I use PHP to check the permission using the Graph API, and then act on the result using JavaScript:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=' . $token;
$permissions = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$has_publish_permission = isset($permissions->data[0]->publish_stream);
?>
var can_publish = <?php echo $has_publish_permission ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;
```

Comment: Hehe yea it should work fine. Guess I could make a django template tag as I'm using python. Although I don't think this is the best solution it's kind of doable, because this way people will have to wait untill the permissions are checked with facebook before the page gets loaded.